# Why are = and <- not equivalent in within()?

Tags: r

```
> within( list(a="a",b="b"), c="c" )
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : argument is missing, with no default
> within( list(a="a",b="b"), c<-"c" )
$a
[1] "a"

$b
[1] "b"

$c
[1] "c"
```

I'm not sure exactly why these two shouldn't be equivalent.  It seems like the the `=` version getting interpreted as an argument named `c` to within because of the `...`.  Is there any way to disable this behavior?  I tried,

```
within( list(a="a",b="b"), `c`="c" )
```

but that fails too.

Comment: For the same reason that `system.time(x = rnorm(1e300))` doesn't work.

Comment: If `=` is the top function call in expression passed to a function, then `=` is understood to be argument assignment. Compare with `within( list(a="a",b="b"), {c="c"})`

Comment: the = sign as an assignment is funky inside functions, R gets confused whether it is an assignment or an argument.

Comment: This also seems to work...`within( list(a="a",b="b"), "="(c,"c") )`, in case you really hate the `<-` assignment. :)

Comment: Frank I love the shameless exploitation of R's operators-are-really-just-functions concept.  But I think @MatthewPlourde wins for ease of implementation. :-)

Comment: @GreenDemon, I wouldnt say that `R` gets confused, but rather is quite clear and on the matter and has documented the behavior well

Comment: Also see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and   and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089066/what-is-the-difference-meaning-between-and-in-data-frame

Comment: @MatthewPlourde and Frank, care to make your comments answers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct that `c="c"` (or any clause of that form) is getting interpreted as a supplied argument. And no, there's no way to disable that -- it's presumably handled down at the level of the R parser.

This difference between `=` and `<-` is documented `?"<-"`

> The operators ‘<-’ and ‘=’ assign into the environment in which
>        they are evaluated.  The operator ‘<-’ can be used anywhere,
>        whereas the operator ‘=’ is only allowed at the top level (e.g.,
>        in the complete expression typed at the command prompt) or as one
>        of the subexpressions in a braced list of expressions.

The prime example of a "braced list of expressions" is a function body, which you can verify by typing, e.g. `is(body(plot.default))`, `length(body(plot.default))`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Every time I encounter something like this I think I learn a little more about how the R parser works.  Now if only I had a free summer or two or three to go wade through the C source and figure out how it *really* works :-)

Comment: @AriB.Friedman -- Hey, don't tempt me to go have a look for myself! I was just happy to finally figure out what that reference to "braced subexpressions" was really getting at, and will count it an accomplishment to have stopped there ;)

Comment: Combining @MatthewPlourde 's suggestion with yours, `is(quote({5^2})` returns `[1] "{"        "language"` just like `is(body(plot.default))` does.

Answer (score 3):

Josh has answered the "why", but at the OP's suggestion, here is another "how":

```
within( list(a="a",b="b"), "="(c,"c") )
# $a
# [1] "a"
#
# $b
# [1] "b"
#
# $c
# [1] "c"
```