# How to combine vectors into one in R

Tags: r, vector

Any experts with R programming can help me with this combining vector question?

### R code shown below:

```
> maxTemps<-0
> for(i in printfilenames) {
+    file2 <- read.csv(i, row.names=1)
+    tempMax <-max(file2[1:145,1], na.rm=TRUE)
+    zero<-vector("numeric", 9)
+      for(i in tempMax) {
+         maxTemps<-tempMax+zero
+         print(tempMax)
+      }
+ }
[1] 24.3
[1] 24.1
[1] 19.4
[1] 21.2
[1] 25.4
[1] 28.7
[1] 22.7
[1] 23.2
[1] 24.2
> maxTemps
[1] 24.2 24.2 24.2 24.2 24.2 24.2 24.2 24.2 24.2
```

This is basically what I am getting.

The question require that my "maxTemps" output should be something like:

```
[1] 24.3 24.1 19.4 21.2 25.4 28.7 22.7 23.2 24.2
```

but I am getting:

```
[1] 24.2 24.2 24.2 24.2 24.2 24.2 24.2 24.2 24.2
```

Anyone can please help me where I got wrong here? Your helps are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the following:

```
 max.temps <- rep(NA, length(printfilenames))

  for(i in 1:length(printfilenames)) {
    file2 <- read.csv(printfilenames[i], row.names=1)
    tempMax <-max(file2[1:145,1], na.rm=TRUE)
    max.temps[i] <- tempMax
   }
```

If I understand correctly, the problem isn't really one of combining vectors but calculating a single value (the maximum from each file) and inserting it into a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Your question and code is very confusing:

1. You execute

   ```
   maxTemps <- tempMax+zero
   ```

   at **every** iteration of your for loop, i.e. you do exactly the same calculation
2. What vectors do you want to combine?
3. You create a zero vector, `zero`, what's the point of adding zero to anything?
4. To answer your question on output, you want something like:

   ```
   maxTemps = numeric(length(tempMax))
   maxTemps[i] = tempMax[i] + zero[i]

   ##Or not inside the for loop
   maxTemps = tempMax + zero
   ##OR
   maxTemps = tempMax
   ```

Comment: Im trying to create a numeric vector full of zeros first, then assigning value i of the vector on the i'th iteration of the loop.

Comment: Just one note: While a matter of style, the usage of `<-` as an assignment operator usually is preferred over `=` in the R-community. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and