# Error using the "prob" package in an R function

Tags: r, probability

I'm attempting to write a function that uses the [prob](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prob/) package to compute conditional probabilities. When using the function I continue to encounter the same error, which states an object within the function cannot be found.

Below is a reproducible example in which I compute a conditional probability without the function and then attempt to use the function to produce the same result. I'm not sure if the error is due to limitations with the prob package or an error on my part.

```
# Load prob package
library(prob)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(30)

# Sample data frame
sampledata <- data.frame(
  X <- sample(1:10),
  Y <- sample(c(-1, 0, 1), 10, replace=TRUE))

# Set probability space
S <- probspace(sampledata)

# Subset Y between -1 and 0
A <- subset(S, Y>=-1 & Y<=0)

# Subset X greater than 6
B <- subset(S, X>6)

# Compute conditional probability
P <- prob(A, given=B)
```

The above code produces the following probability:

```
> P
[1] 0.25
```

Attempting to write a function to calculate the same probability:

```
# Create function with data frame, variables, and conditional inputs
prob.function <- function(df, variable1, variable2, state1, state2, cond1){
  s <- probspace(df)
  a <- subset(s, variable1>=state1 & variable1<=state2)
  b <- subset(s, variable2>cond1)
  p <- prob(a, given=b)
  return(p)
}

# Demonstrate the function
test <- prob.function(sampledata, Y, X, -1, 0, 6)
```

This function gives the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'b' not found
```

Any help you can provide would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your question and thank you for the offline bug report.  After playing with it and now reading this discussion there is more work to do.  I expect an update on R-Forge later tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `prob`.

When I run this in Vanilla R, I get the same error.  But when I create an object `b` in my workspace, the error disapears:

```
> print(b)
Error in print(b) : object 'b' not found
> test <- prob.function(sampledata, Y, X, -1, 0, 6)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'b' not found
>
> b <- "dummy variable"
> print(b)
[1] "dummy variable"
> test <- prob.function(sampledata, Y, X, -1, 0, 6)
> test
[1] 0.25
>
```

As a temporary workaround, just create a dummy `b` in your current environment.

---

As for the bug, if you look at the source for `prob.default` (which in the example above is what `prob(a, given=b)` is eventually calling), you'll see the following section:

```
if (missing(given)) {
    < cropped >
}
else {
    f <- substitute(given)
    g <- eval(f, x)                  <~~~~ 
    if (!is.logical(g)) {            <~~~~
        if (!is.data.frame(given))   <~~~~
            stop("'given' must be data.frame or evaluate to logical")
        B <- given

    }
    ...
    < cropped >
}
```

it is jumping from `g` to `given`, perhaps inadvertently?    I would reach out to the package maintainer, as this may be an oversight.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I'll notify the package author of this error.

Comment: Thank you, Ricardo, for identifying where the problem lies.

Comment: @G.JayKerns no problem at all.  I think there might be a similar issue in the other `prob` methods and might be worth looking into.  Thanks for the package

Answer (score 1):

I *don't* think this is a bug in package `prob`.

First, you should create you `sampledata` as

```
sampledata <- data.frame(
  X = sample(1:10),
  Y = sample(c(-1, 0, 1), 10, replace=TRUE))
```

Your original code creates not only this dataframe but also  variables `X` and `Y` in the global environment which are actually being used later when you call your function.

Second, you shouldn't call `subset()` inside a function. Use bracket subsetting instead:

```
prob.function <- function(df, variable1, variable2, state1, state2, cond1){
  s <- probspace(df)
  a <- s[s[[variable1]]>=state1 & s[[variable1]]<=state2, ]
  b <- s[s[[variable2]]>cond1, ]
  p <- prob(a, given=b)
  return(p)
}
```

And pass `variable1` and `variable2` as strings:

```
test <- prob.function(sampledata, "Y", "X", -1, 0, 6)
```

Now you have `test==0.25`, and no error.

References for what is going on:

- http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#non-standard-evaluation-in-subset
- [Assignment operators in R: '=' and '<-'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and/)
- [Why is `[` better than `subset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset)

Comment: Hey @Ferdinand, while I think your advice on not using subset is spot on, I still think there is something fishy going on with `prob` and likely to be a bug. Notice the part about different responses from the function based on what is in my working environment, where the only relation to the function is a shared object name (but the value having no connection to the function).   Not to mention this still does not work when run in `R --vanilla`  :/

Comment: @RicardoSaporta You're right, it's a bug. He forgot `enclos=parent.frame()` in `eval(f, x)`. At that point, `f` contains the symbol `b`, and `x` contains the dataframe `a`. Since the default enclosing for `eval` is the frame calling it, the parser will look for `b` in `prob`'s namespace and up, bypassing the "call stack" where the real `b` is. When you create a dummy `b`, `eval` does not throw an error, `is.logical(g)` is FALSE (it's a string) but `is.data.frame(given)` is TRUE, because `given` is the real `b`, not the promise. A bug hard to find! :-)

Comment: Hi @Ferdinand.kraft, thanks for your very helpful advice, especially regarding when/how to use subset(). Now that it appears the problem is with a bug in the package, I've sent the package author an email with a link to this discussion. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you, Ferdinand.  When I first started working on this, I went down the same path you did (using `=` instead of `<-`, and so forth).  Now that I've read your extended comment above, though, it is clear that there is a more serious problem.  I will try your suggested `enclose=parent.frame()`.  Thanks again.