# Using an if and else statement with a for loop in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I am not sure I quite understand how to use an if and else statement within a for loop. My code looks like this:

```
> X
[1] 1 0 1 1 1
A=0
for (i in 1:5){
if (X[i]=1)
A=A+1
}
else{
A=A
}
```

for example in this case there are 4 '1's in the vector X. So for every 1 in the vector I want it to add 1 to the value of A. (So A should equal 4).

Comment: It has to be `if(X[i] == 1)`. Additionally your example needs a `{` and a `}`. Your `else` block is useless. What is your question?

Comment: This would be a relatively unusual thing to do in R, I think. The idiomatic way to get what you want is simply `A <- sum(X)`. Does that answer your question? If not, could expand your question?

Comment: Or say that X wasn't conveniently kinda Boolean already, e.g. `X <- c("cow", "pig", "cow", "cow", "cow")`. You could get the same count with `A <- sum(X %in% "cow")`. The `X %in% "cow"` comparison creates a logical vector that `sum()` can still add up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned: `=` is for assignment (similar to `<-`; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and) for details) and `==` is to compare equality.

You final loop should be:

```
for(i in X){
  if (i == 1) A <- A + 1
}
```

You don't need the `else` clause because it doesn't really do anything, just slows down the loop slightly.

R is vectorized though so use that fact.  It is more idiomatic to say:

```
sum(X)
```

if you want to count them all up or look at `apply` and `lapply` for more complex situations, depending on the context of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
X <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
A <- 0

for (i in X){
   if (i == 1)
    A <- A + 1
   else A <- A + 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are after:

```
for (i in 1:5){
  if (X[i]==1){
    A=A+1
  }else{
    A=A  
  }
}
```

Notice the double `=` sign in `X[i]==1`gives you your falsifiable boolean statement (does `X[i]` equal `1`), compared to the single `=` sign in your example which sets `X[i]` equal to `1`

Comment: You've got to be careful with `==`, though - if `X` contained any `NA`s, this would throw an error. `%in%` is safer, to the point that I almost never use `==` at all.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison sign should be (`X[i]==1`) and the way you are using the if statement is fine. But you got extra braces which is messing up your code.

it should look like this

```
X <- c(1,0,1,1,1)
A=0
for (i in 1:5){
    if (X[i]==1)
        A=A+1
    else
        A=A
}
```

or like this

```
X <- c(1,0,1,1,1)
A=0
for (i in 1:5){
    if (X[i]==1){
        A=A+1
    }
    else{
        A=A
    }
}
```

If you have just one instruction within an if statement you don't need the braces, but if more two or more instructions will run for a certain condition the braces are necessary.

The indentation is there only to help the visualisation.

Comment: No problem.  Comment withdrawn.