# Running the same function multiple times and saving results with different names in workspace

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, workspace, euclidean-distance

So, I built a function called **sort.song**.

My goal with this function is to randomly sample the rows of a data.frame (DATA) and then filter it out (DATA.NEW) to analyse it. I want to do it multiple times (let's say 10 times). By the end, I want that each object (mantel.something) resulted from this function to be saved in my workspace with a name that I can relate to each cycle (mantel.something1, mantel.somenthing2...mantel.something10).

I have the following code, so far:

```
 sort.song<-function(DATA){
  require(ade4)
  for(i in 1:10){ # Am I using for correctly here?

   DATA.NEW <- DATA[sample(1:nrow(DATA),replace=FALSE),]
   DATA.NEW <- DATA.NEW[!duplicated(DATA.NEW$Point),]

   coord.dist<-dist(DATA.NEW[,4:5],method="euclidean")
   num.notes.dist<-dist(DATA.NEW$Num_Notes,method="euclidean")
   songdur.dist<-dist(DATA.NEW$Song_Dur,method="euclidean")
   hfreq.dist<-dist(DATA.NEW$High_Freq,method="euclidean")
   lfreq.dist<-dist(DATA.NEW$Low_Freq,method="euclidean")
   bwidth.dist<-dist(DATA.NEW$Bwidth_Song,method="euclidean")
   hfreqlnote.dist<-dist(DATA.NEW$HighFreq_LastNote,method="euclidean")

   mantel.numnotes[i]<<-mantel.rtest(coord.dist,num.notes.dist,nrepet=1000)
   mantel.songdur[i]<<-mantel.rtest(coord.dist,songdur.dist,nrepet=1000)
   mantel.hfreq[i]<<-mantel.rtest(coord.dist,hfreq.dist,nrepet=1000)
   mantel.lfreq[i]<<-mantel.rtest(coord.dist,lfreq.dist,nrepet=1000)
   mantel.bwidth[i]<<-mantel.rtest(coord.dist,bwidth.dist,nrepet=1000)
   mantel.hfreqlnote[i]<<-mantel.rtest(coord.dist,hfreqlnote.dist,nrepet=1000)
   }
}
```

Could someone please help me to do it the right way?

I think I'm not assigning the cycles correctly for each mantel.somenthing object.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider making the whole process a function, then you can repeat it multiple times using the replicate function.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about it? What do you mean by "making the whole process a function"?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in response, but see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to implement what you are trying to do is through a `list`. You can even make it take two indices, the first for the iterations, the second for the type of analysis.

```
mantellist <- as.list(1:10)   ## initiate list with some values
for (i in 1:10){
...
mantellist[[i]] <- list(numnotes=mantel.rtest(coord.dist,num.notes.dist,nrepet=1000),
                        songdur=mantel.rtest(coord.dist,songdur.dist,nrepet=1000),
                        hfreq=mantel.rtest(coord.dist,hfreq.dist,nrepet=1000),
                        ...)
}
return(mantellist)
```

In this way you can index your specific analysis for each iteration in an intuitive way:

```
mantellist[[2]][['hfreq']]
mantellist[[2]]$hfreq       ## alternative
```

EDIT by Mohr:
Just for clarification...

So, according to your suggestion the code should be something like this:

```
sort.song<-function(DATA){
  require(ade4)
  mantellist <- as.list(1:10) 
  for(i in 1:10){
    DATA.NEW <- DATA[sample(1:nrow(DATA),replace=FALSE),]
    DATA.NEW <- DATA.NEW[!duplicated(DATA.NEW$Point),]

    coord.dist<-dist(DATA.NEW[,4:5],method="euclidean")
    num.notes.dist<-dist(DATA.NEW$Num_Notes,method="euclidean")
    songdur.dist<-dist(DATA.NEW$Song_Dur,method="euclidean")
    hfreq.dist<-dist(DATA.NEW$High_Freq,method="euclidean")
    lfreq.dist<-dist(DATA.NEW$Low_Freq,method="euclidean")
    bwidth.dist<-dist(DATA.NEW$Bwidth_Song,method="euclidean")
    hfreqlnote.dist<-dist(DATA.NEW$HighFreq_LastNote,method="euclidean")

    mantellist[[i]] <- list(numnotes=mantel.rtest(coord.dist,num.notes.dist,nrepet=1000),
                       songdur=mantel.rtest(coord.dist,songdur.dist,nrepet=1000),
                       hfreq=mantel.rtest(coord.dist,hfreq.dist,nrepet=1000),
                       lfreq=mantel.rtest(coord.dist,lfreq.dist,nrepet=1000),
                       bwidth=mantel.rtest(coord.dist,bwidth.dist,nrepet=1000),
                       hfreqlnote=mantel.rtest(coord.dist,hfreqlnote.dist,nrepet=1000)
                       )
  }
  return(mantellist)
}
```

Comment: Hey, I edited your post just to check if I got it right...did I?

Comment: Yup, that's why I approved it. Sorry I missed your earlier message.

Comment: Many thanks! If I had at least 15 points I would vote for your answer! :)
EDIT: Well..now I got it! Thanks one more time.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the question at the end, you know, for posterity :-)

Comment: Just one more thing...
How do I use this information:

mantellist[[2]][['hfreq']]...I always get NULL


mantellist[[2]]$hfreq

Comment: If the object generates correctly in the loop you should be able to access it and plug it into a function: `summary(mantellist[[2]]$hfreq)`

Comment: Probably I didn't understood it correctly.  I'm running the function exactly as it is in your message. I'm doing this: a<-sort.song(DATA)
Then when I try a[[2]]$hfreq it gives me NULL.

Comment: Fixed the syntax on the `list()`. Try now please.

Comment: It worked. But, what's the difference between <- and = ? I always thought it was the same thing!

Comment: It's subtle, and explained best [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and). In this case you don't want the list elements to exist as separate variables in the function environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your objective of repeating this exercise 10 (or more times) without using an explicit `for`-loop. Rather than have the function run the loop, write the `sort.song` function to run one iteration of the process, then you can use `replicate` to repeat that process however many times you desire.

It is generally good practice not to create a bunch of named objects in your global environment. Instead, you can hold of the results of each iteration of this process in a single object. [`replicate`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/lapply.html) will return an array (if possible) otherwise a list (in the example below, a list of lists). So, the list will have 10 elements (one for each iteration) and each element will itself be a list containing named elements corresponding to each result of `mantel.rtest`.

```
sort.song<-function(DATA){
   DATA.NEW <- DATA[sample(1:nrow(DATA),replace=FALSE),]
   DATA.NEW <- DATA.NEW[!duplicated(DATA.NEW$Point),]

   coord.dist <- dist(DATA.NEW[,4:5],method="euclidean")
   num.notes.dist <- dist(DATA.NEW$Num_Notes,method="euclidean")
   songdur.dist <- dist(DATA.NEW$Song_Dur,method="euclidean")
   hfreq.dist <- dist(DATA.NEW$High_Freq,method="euclidean")
   lfreq.dist <- dist(DATA.NEW$Low_Freq,method="euclidean")
   bwidth.dist <- dist(DATA.NEW$Bwidth_Song,method="euclidean")
   hfreqlnote.dist <- dist(DATA.NEW$HighFreq_LastNote,method="euclidean")

   return(list(
      numnotes = mantel.rtest(coord.dist,num.notes.dist,nrepet=1000),
      songdur = mantel.rtest(coord.dist,songdur.dist,nrepet=1000),
      hfreq = mantel.rtest(coord.dist,hfreq.dist,nrepet=1000),
      lfreq = mantel.rtest(coord.dist,lfreq.dist,nrepet=1000),
      bwidth = mantel.rtest(coord.dist,bwidth.dist,nrepet=1000),
      hfreqlnote = mantel.rtest(coord.dist,hfreqlnote.dist,nrepet=1000)
   ))
}

require(ade4)
replicate(10, sort.song(DATA))
```