# Subset of data for specific plot layer

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to

- plot all data on some layers 
  (here: *geom_point*)
- plot only a subset on some other layers 
  (here: *geom_text* for type "range")

However, I'm getting the text labels for the whole data, while they should only be added for the turquoise points.

I tried subsetting the data, but the output is not the desired. Still, the object *sub_data* holds only the wanted data.

Any suggestions?

---

**R code:**

```
library(ggplot2)

N <- 10

# create 20 = 2*10 data points
test_data <- data.frame(
  idx  <- c( 1:N, 1:N ),
  vals <- c( runif(N, 0, 1),
             rep(  0.5, N)),
  type <- c( rep("range",  N),
             rep("const",  N))
)

# this subsets to the 10 data points of type "range"
sub_data <- subset( test_data, type == "range")

ggplot( test_data, aes( x = idx, y = vals)) + 
  geom_point( aes( colour = type)) +
  geom_text(  data = sub_data, aes( x = idx + 0.1, label = idx ), size = 3.5)
```

**output:**
[image]

Comment: I tested your code and I get the desired result. The problem is that you are using `<-` inside the `data.frame` command instead of `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `<-` to `=` inside your `data.frame` command, like this:

```
test_data <- data.frame(
  idx  = c(1:N, 1:N),
  vals = c(runif(N, 0, 1), rep(  0.5, N)),
  type = c(rep("range", N), rep("const",  N))
)
```

Then execute your plot code and you should get the desired result.

An alternative to creating a dataframe in a correct way is:

```
idx <- c(1:N, 1:N),
vals <- c(runif(N, 0, 1), rep(  0.5, N)),
type <- c(rep("range", N), rep("const",  N))
test_data <- data.frame(idx, vals, type)
```

For more background on the difference between the `<-` and the `=` assignment operators, see [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and)

Comment: Thanks. I 'love' those moments, where the bug lies in so few letters.
Still I don't really get, why I can't use '<-' in this case.

Comment: @Jaap: Should one only use '=' and not '<-' while creating dataframe? Some further explanation on = vs <- in this case will be much appreciated.