# R <- or = operators, why is <- necessary in this case?

Tags: r, operators

I have read [past SO questions about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and) and their example as to why we need to use <- not = does not seem applicable (at least in the recent versions).

```
median(x = 1:10)  # Should give an error but both work just fine.
x   

median(x <- 1:10)
x
```

I always use =, BUT seem to finally found a case where <- is necessary but don't understand why, can anyone tell me why <- is necessary here and = does not work. Thank you.

```
x=c(2,4,6)
names(x)=c('a','b','c')
x

# OR we can do this, but it requires a <-

x='names<-'(x, value=c('a','b','d'))
x='names='(x, value=c('a','b','d'))   #Error: could not find function "names="
x
```

Comment: Because `names<-` is an actual function.  And its name is defined to be `names<-`  whereas `names=` does not exist as a function

Comment: `=` is used to pass arguments to functions, and `<-` cannot be used for this.  Your second expression (`median( x <- 1:10)`) has the side-effect of creating `x` in the enclosing environment, but does not name the argument passed to `median`.

Comment: If you want to delete your question, I've deleted my answer.

Comment: There are cases where you pass an expression to a function, where `<-` is required. Compare: `system.time(x<-3)` and `system.time(x=3)`.