# Meaning of the <- symbol in Python

Tags: python

I am reading a Python book that uses the symbol

> <-

It seems to be used interchangeably with the = sign. Is this a normal symbol to explain this? I have never seen it used elsewhere. 
[image]

Comment: The difference of these assignment operators is actually a more [popular discussion in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and). Possibly, your citation referred to R and not Python?

Comment: Definitely R syntax.

Comment: I suppose it could be the `(*p).` C operator in a right-to-left language. But seriously, it is poor typesetting for the symbol `←` which I've seen used  mostly in pseudo-code. It is pronounced "gets" as in "userAge gets 0".

Comment: This isn't a question about Python at all -- it's a question about syntax and typography in the book you're reading, which *wasn't* following Python convention in that example.

Comment: Now that I know the answer, I absolutely agree it is no longer a Python question.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a symbol, it's simply showing that when you make an assignment using '=' you are placing the value on the right into the variable on the left.

Answer (score 6):

`a <- b` (better formatted as `a < -b`) means "a less than minus b" , so

```
>>> a = -5
>>> b = 3
>>> a <- b
True

>>> a = 3
>>> b = 4
>>> a <- b
False
```

In your image, as others have pointed out, the author is just indicating an assignment, it's unfortunate that the typography made it look like code, it wasn't meant to be a "less than minus".

Comment: The only accurate answer.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, it's only accurate at answering a question that only came up by misreading the text; the text *clearly* did not in fact mean that `userAge <- 0` was valid Python syntax at all (though it is indeed so, that's strictly coincidental).

Comment: @Charles I wouldn't say "clearly", because, as Roshan Mathews points out, it was formatted as code, and could be confusing to the reader.

Comment: Granted, it's only clear when taking context into account; reading it out of context is, I'd argue, what prompted the OP to ask this question.

Comment: I'll have to use this in a code obfuscation challenge sometime

Answer (score 4):

It's just a pseudo-code example, not Python syntax.