# R: Why does data.frame only give me nice column names if I use the = operator?

Tags: r, dataframe, assignment-operator

These four ways of creating a `dataframe` look pretty similar to me:

```
myData1 <- data.frame(a <- c(1,2), b <- c(3, 4))
myData2 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2), b = c(3,4))
myData3 <- data.frame(`<-`(a,c(1,2)), `<-`(b,c(3, 4)))
myData4 <- data.frame(`=`(a,c(1,2)), `=`(b,c(3,4)))
```

But If I print out the column names, I only get the nice column names that I would hope for if I use the `=` operator.  In all the other cases, the *whole expression* becomes the column name, with all the non-alphanumerics replaced by periods:

```
> colnames(myData1)
[1] "a....c.1..2." "b....c.3..4."
> colnames(myData2)
[1] "a" "b"
> colnames(myData3)
[1] "a....c.1..2." "b....c.3..4."
> colnames(myData4)
[1] "a...c.1..2." "b...c.3..4."
```

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and?lq=1) about differences between `<-` and `=` when used in function calls in terms of variable scope, but as far as I can reason (possibly not very far), that doesn't explain this particular behavior.

1. What accounts for the difference between `=` and `<-`?
2. What accounts for the difference between the prefix and infix versions of `=`?

Comment: Well, to be fair, your examples 1, 3 and 4 are very rare, bordering on pathological.

Comment: Haha I love that description.  I added examples 3 and 4 as a curiosity after finding the linked post, which says they should be equivalent.  But the first example is what I typed naturally (read: naively).  Could you explain what's wrong with them?

Comment: The root of the "problem" is `list(a <- 1:2)`, but that descends to R's internals almost immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function, including `data.frame`, `=` is not used as an assignment operator. It simply marks relationships between given parameter and a variable you pass to the function.

Ignoring `data.frame(a = c(1,2), b = c(3,4))`, fore each of these calls  `<-` and `=` are interpreted as normal assignments and create `a` and `b` variables in your environment.

```
> ls()
character(0)
> myData1 <- data.frame(a <- c(1,2), b <- c(3, 4))
[1] "a"       "b"       "myData1"
> rm(list=ls())
> ls()
character(0)
> myData3 <- data.frame(`<-`(a,c(1,2)), `<-`(b,c(3, 4)))
> ls()
[1] "a"       "b"       "myData3"
> rm(list=ls())
> ls()
character(0)
> myData4 <- data.frame(`=`(a,c(1,2)), `=`(b,c(3,4)))
> ls()
[1] "a"       "b"       "myData4"
```

Data frame get expected values only because `<-` and `=` return invisibly the argument.

```
> foo <- `=`(a,c(1,2))
> foo
[1] 1 2
```

Because of that your `data.frame` calls are equivalent, ignoring variable assignment side effect, to

```
> data.frame(c(1,2), c(3, 4))
  c.1..2. c.3..4.
1       1       3
2       2       4
```

hence the results you see.

Comment: Also consider `colnames(data.frame(x = a <- c(1,2), y = b <- c(3, 4)))`

Answer (score 2):

When you offer `a <- c(1,2)` as an argument to data.frame, there will be a value for the first argument, but there will be no name in the formals list. The formals of a function are processed with `as.list`. Both `a` and `c(1,2)` were passed to `<-` and an element named `a` is returned and this results in there being no name in the arguments that got sent to `as.list`. You can think of the symbol `a` as having already been already processed and therefore "used up". The default names in that situation are the results of a `deparse`call.

```
> make.names(deparse( quote(a <- c(1,2) )) )
[1] "a....c.1..2."
```