# Function not working withing R function

Tags: r

I'm new to R and was trying to write a function to search for an object in all the environments.

The following piece of lines work fine but when I include them inside a 'while' loop, they don't work. I think I'm missing something here. Any help?

```
    name<-10
    env=parent.frame()
    !identical(env,emptyenv())
    exists('name',envir=env,inherits = FALSE)
    env<-parent.env(env)
    env
```

## Codes in while loop

```
    MyWhere<-function(name,env=parent.frame){
       while(!identical(env,emptyenv())){
    if (exists(name,envir=env,inherits = FALSE)) {
        env
       }
    else {
        env<-parent.env(env)
        }
      }
    }

    MyWhere('a')
```

Error message - Error in exists(name, envir = env, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument

Comment: Note that in R, usage of spaces around the `<-` operator is [usually encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and).

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo: you need to add parentheses in the call to parent.frame()

```
MyWhere<-function(name,env=parent.frame()){
```

Without the parentheses you're passing in a 'function' instead of an 'environment' object, resulting in the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems here. The error you're getting is because you're passing `parent.env`, a function, instead of `parent.env()`, an environment, as the default environment value.

Further, you don't return the environment when you match the name, which leads to an infinite loop when your function matches. Lastly, the function doesn't return the empty environment when it doesn't match.

When you fix these, it seems to work:

```
MyWhere<-function(name,env=parent.frame()){
  while(!identical(env,emptyenv())){
    if (exists(name,envir=env,inherits = FALSE)) {
      return(env)
    } else {
      env<-parent.env(env)
    }
  }
  return(env)
}

foo <- 3
MyWhere('foo')
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
MyWhere('blah')
# <environment: R_EmptyEnv>
library(ggplot2)
MyWhere('geom_line')
# <environment: package:ggplot2>
# attr(,"name")
# [1] "package:ggplot2"
# attr(,"path")
# [1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/ggplot2"
```