# store results of for loop in unique objects

Tags: r, for-loop

Here is a simple loop

```
 for (i in seq(1,30)) {
    mdl<-i
 }
```

How do I get 30 `mdl` rather than just one `mdl` (which is happening because within the loop, `mdli` is being replaced by `mdli+1` at every iteration. What I want is to have 30 `mdl` perhaps with names like `mdl1`, `mdl2` ....`mdl30`

I tried this:

```
for (i in seq(1,30)) {
   mdli<-i
 }
```

But if I type `mdl1`, it says `mdl1 not found` whereas typing `mdli` gives me the value of `i=5`

Thank you

Comment: `mdl <- integer(30)` outside the loop (first), and `mdl[i] <- i` inside the loop.  This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620557/simple-function-in-r/32620651#32620651

Comment: thanks. But is there any way I don't have to specify `mdl<-integer(30)` beforehand. I am not sure how many mdl I will have since the data is very big. I was just wondering if there is any way I can make mdl take the name of value corresponding to i

Comment: But you have a sequence of known length so it makes sense to allocate the vector of the same length as the length of the sequence in the `for()` statement.

Comment: thanks for the help.

Comment: Btw, for names you could do `mdl <- NULL; for(i in 1:10)  mdl[paste0("mdl", i)] <- i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your store variable beforhand without determine how many values it shall store. If you want for each value a seperate variable take a look at the `paste` function.

```
x<- NULL
for (i in 1:10){
x[i] <- i*2
}
```

*edit: The comment above is right. This way is not the most efficent one. But I still use it when computation time is not an issue.