# Why doesn't rm(ls()) work and "list" is needed?

Tags: r, syntax

I just got started learning R with the "datacamp" site and I ran into a syntax misunderstanding at the beginning.

It says that `rm(list = ls())` is a very useful command to clear everything from your workspace but I don't understand what `list =` is for.

- a. They haven't yet taught me the meaning of `=` in R and I didn't find an explanation at the documentation. `=` is like `<-`? What's the difference?
- b. If the input of `rm()` can be a list of variables names, and the output of `ls()` is a list of var names, why can't I just use `rm(ls())`?

Comment: Do `help(rm)` to see what parameters `rm` takes. `list` is the name of one of the parameters. You can supply parameters to functions positionally and/or with explicit names. The reason for the explicit name here that the function parameter list starts with `...`. If you don't specify one of the named parameters by name, `rm` has no idea of your intent since you can remove any number of individual objects in the environment with `rm` in the same call. This is the only time (IMO) that you should use `=` is when performing function parameter assignments.

Comment: Dupe #1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and

Comment: Short answer, `ls()` has quotes (is a character vector) and the `...` argument in `help(rm)` says it only accepts unquoted names

Comment: This is not a bad question. Ignore the downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

**Passing arguments by position vs name**

The `=` symbol plays a special role in naming arguments to a function call.

Consider two essentially identical functions:

```
f <- function(..., y=3) (2+sum(...))^y
g <- function(y=3, ...) (2+sum(...))^y
```

If `y=` is not named, the results are generally different:

```
f(y=5) # 32
g(y=5) # 32

f(5)   # 343
g(5)   # 32
```

`rm` is like `f` -- type `?rm` to see -- so if you want to call `rm(list = ls())`, write it out in full.

**Representing object names**

In most of R, if you write `f(g())`, evaluation flows naturally:

- `g()` is evaluated to `8` and substituted into `f(g())` for `f(8)`
- `f(8)` is evaluated to `1000`

`rm` breaks this pattern in its unnamed `...` arguments, which basically just exist for interactive use. Only manually typed variable names are allowed.† As a result, `rm(ls())` won't run.

Hadley Wickham [provides another nice example](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#nse-downsides):

> ```
> ggplot2 <- "plyr"
> library(ggplot2) # loads ggplot2, not plyr!
> ```

---

<sub>† Okay, you can use the `...` without manually typed names, like</sub>

```
do.call(library, as.list(ggplot2)) # loads plyr!
```

<sub>but don't mess with that unless you know what you're doing.</sub>

Comment: But also note that if you have `X` and `Y` in the workspace, with  `rm()` you **can** do `rm("X", "Y")`  but you **cannot** do `rm(ls())`.  This is what I am having trouble grasping.

Comment: @RichardScriven Yeah, even if there's just `x`, like `rm(list=ls()); x=1`, you can't do `rm(ls())`... I'm trying to think of some other examples with such abnormal evaluation rules. Oh, here's one: `mylib = "data.table"; library(mylib) # error`. I'm guessing it's most prevalent in old base functions and the hadleyverse.

Comment: So, something happens internally which makes `rm(ls())` impossible.  Note that `.Internal(remove(ls(), .GlobalEnv, FALSE))` does work, and `rm()` calls this at the end (for the basic case).