# Remove iterations of carett::train() on knit html output

Tags: r, knitr, r-caret

Using the following code with Knit HTML in Rstudio

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
library(caret)
tc <- trainControl(method="boot",number=25)
train = train(Species~.,data=iris,method="nnet",trControl=tc)
confusionMatrix(train)
```
````

How to avoid the `train` iteration print on my html file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested in [@Swiss12000's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446743/remove-iterations-of-caretttrain-on-knit-html-output#comment59068020_35477986), the argument `trace = FALSE` can be passed to `train` to suppress the messages.

This behaviour is not documented in `?train` because the parameter is passed (via `...`) to the method `nnet`. `trace = FALSE` will only work for methods that support this parameter. In other cases, the `capture.output` approach below might still be useful.

---

`caret::train` prints messages to `stdout`, unsolicitedly. That's nasty. The output can be suppressed by wrapping the expression in `capture.output()`:

```
garbage <- capture.output(train <- train(Species~.,data=iris,method="nnet",trControl=tc))
```

Note that this is one of the cases where the [differentce between the assignment operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and) matters: `capture.output(train = train(...` doesn't work, probably because the assignment is interpreted as an argument to `train()`.

In order to additionally suppress the package startup messages, add the [chunk option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/) `message = FALSE`.

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(caret)
tc <- trainControl(method = "boot",number = 25)
garbage <- capture.output(
  train <- train(Species ~ ., data = iris, method = "nnet", trControl = tc))
confusionMatrix(train)
```
````

Output:

> ## test
>
> ```
> ## Bootstrapped (25 reps) Confusion Matrix 
> ## 
> ## (entries are percentages of table totals)
> ##  
> ##             Reference
> ## Prediction   setosa versicolor virginica
> ##   setosa       33.8        0.0       0.0
> ##   versicolor    0.0       31.0       1.1
> ##   virginica     0.0        2.0      32.1
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I also discover there is the TRACE=FALSE param

Comment: @Swiss12000 Oh, thank you for the hint. I added it to the answer.