# R: Is there any performance difference between using = or <-?

Tags: r, performance, assignment-operator

For example:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
```

or

```
a = c(1,2,3).
```

Obviously for small data frames or lists, it won't matter at all. I am thinking more about big datasets or using them inside a for-loop.

Comment: If there's no difference as @duffymo says when shall I use = or <-?

Comment: Lots of previous discussion is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and Most people don't give a flying about what any individual prefers to use as it is really fringe difference stuff.

Comment: @duffymo, post as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No measurable performance difference; more about readability and convention. It's all the computations that R is doing that will make or break you.

Use `<-`; ["R In Action"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617291382) says on page 7 that it's standard and other R developers will make fun of you if you don't.

There might be a deeper reason in the [R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html):

> There are three different assignment operators: two of them have
>   leftwards and rightwards forms.
>
> The operators <- and = assign into the environment in which they are
>   evaluated.
>
> The operator <- can be used anywhere, **whereas the operator = is only
>   allowed at the top level** (e.g., in the complete expression typed at
>   the command prompt) or as one of the subexpressions in a braced list
>   of expressions.

It's usually a good idea to use the proper idiom of the language you're writing in.