# R - creating variable from reading line

Tags: r

I would like to create a variable *XO* from user's answer on a quick question. And I also would like system to write, what user has selected. The code looks like this:

```
fun1 <- function() {
XO <- readline(prompt = "Do you want X, or O? ")
if (substr(XO, 1, 1) == "X")
  cat("You have chosen X.\n") & XO = "X"
 else
  cat("You have chosen O.\n") & XO = "O"
}
```

The function *fun1* is created properly, but after answering the question (my answer is e.g. "X"), system shows error:

```
Error in cat("You have chosen X.\n") & XO = "X" : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

And *XO* is not created.

Please, could you help me, what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R`, `&` is just used in logical assignments, not for joining sentences.
What you wanna do is to put that piece of code in a chunks inside curly brackets `{}` and split them in different lines. If the condition is true `R` will run the hole chunk inside the curly brackets.

```
fun1 <- function() {
  XO <- readline(prompt = "Do you want X, or O? ")
  if (substr(XO, 1, 1) == "X") {
    cat("You have chosen X.\n")
    XO <<- "X"
  } else {
    cat("You have chosen O.\n")
    XO <<- "O"
  }
}
```

You're using `=` to assign the `XO` variable inside the `fun1` function. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and) to be sure that's what you want. If you want it to be available also in the global environment, use `<<-` instead.

Comment: Thank you for help. However, when I run the code you wrote, the system tells me, that object "XO" is not found. Do you know, how to solve this problem?