# Assignment in definition of data.frame

Tags: r, parsing, assignment-operator

This one is not strictly a problem, but a thing that I encountered by accident. However, it is really intriguing to me.

I've run the following line in my console

```
sc_matrix <- data.frame(sc_start<-rpois(n=15, 0.4), sc_end<-rpois(n=15, 0.3))
```

and I was really surprised that the output was

```
head(sc_matrix, n=5)
#   sc_start....rpois.n...15..0.4. sc_end....rpois.n...15..0.3.
#1                               0                            1
#2                               0                            2
#3                               0                            0
#4                               1                            1
#5                               0                            0
```

First, I was surprised because the interpreter understood me (without even a warning). The `data.frame` was created even though I have used `<-` assignment inside of the `data.frame` constructor.

Second, the `colnames` seems to be created according to the rule change all non-alpha-numeric into `.`(dot) and use it as a name.

After reading the discussion on [assignments comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and) I guess my question is:

How R handles that line of code? Since there is no `=` operator it evaluates each argument, e.g. `sc_start<-rpois(n=15, 0.4)`, creates column name from it and uses the value of the right-side evaluation?

It seems tricky, since the operator `<-` does not return any value and I would guess the created `data.frame` should contain something like `NULL`.
I will appreciate any comments on this.

Comment: The points within the colnames are probably generated by `make.names()`, which states in the documentary: `A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters [..] All invalid characters are translated to ".".`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sc_matrix <- data.frame(sc_start<-rpois(n=15, 0.4), sc_end<-rpois(n=15, 0.3))
```

To understand what happens here, you need to know that like almost everything in R (except data objects) `<-` is actually a function. You can even do things like `` `<-`(a, 1) ``. This function has an invisible return value, which is the RHS of the assignment (see `help("<-")`), i.e., your assumption is wrong.

If you don't pass column names to `data.frame` (as the LHS of `=`) it uses `substitute` to create names. These names are sanitized if `check.names = TRUE`, the default. What you observe is essentially the same as if you do something like `data.frame(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, by

```
sc_start <- rpois(n=15, 0.4)
```

you actually assign the result of `rpois(n=15, 0.4)` to the variable `sc_start`. The same holds for `sc_end <- rpois(n=15, 0.3)`.

After creating the data frame, you will notice that those variables are created and placed in your global environment.

What you do is basically the same as

```
data.frame(rpois(n=15, 0.4), rpois(n=15, 0.3))
```

in which the column names are not specified explicitly and thus R creates them automatically unless `fix.empty.names` is set to `FALSE`. The only difference is that you keep the result of each column in a variable. That is, `sc_start` and `sc_end`.

Check the result of

```
data.frame(x = sc_start <- rpois(n=15, 0.4), y = sc_end <- rpois(n=15, 0.3))
```

You will notice that the column names are `x` and `y` due to `=` operator and `sc_start` and `sc_end` are in your global environment due to `<-` operator.

Comment: I've marked @Roland as the answer, but your remarks are also insightful, thanks!