# How do I change column typings via for loop?

Tags: r

I have a df that where some columns are type character and I would like them to be integer values. I know I can switch typing using as.integer:

```
df$i <- as.integer(df$i)
```

But I would like to have a loop change a bunch of columns instead of having to run the command multiple times. Here's my code so far:

```
cols_to_change = c(37:49, 53:61)
  for(i in cols_to_change)
  {
    class(df[, i])  <- 'integer'
  }
```

I'm getting an error that a list object can't be converted to type 'integer', where am I wrong here? Is there an easier way to do this using one of the apply functions?

Comment: There are lots of options here, but you might as a first step just trying using `as.integer` in the for loop like you normally would: `df[,i] <- as.integer(df[,i])`.

Comment: One more thing: It is generally preferable to use `<-` instead of `=` in R [for a couple of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/what-are-the-differences-between-and-in-r).

Comment: For best results avoid using for loop. You can easily change the specific columns to integer using `mutate_at`, `mutate_if `, `mutate_all` etc in `dplyr` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way to do this would be to use `dplyr::mutate_at`:

```
df <- dplyr::mutate_at(df, c(37:49, 53:61), as.integer)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `purrr::map` or `lapply` offer fairly elegant solutions here (and just say no to for-loops in R if possible):

Let's make you a fake data frame with all character vectors:

```
> df <- data.frame(let1 = c('a', 'b', 'c'), num1 = c('1', '2', '3'),
             let2 = c('d', 'e', 'f'), num2 = c('4', '5', '6'),
             num3 = c('7', '8', '9'), let3 = c('g', 'h', 'i'),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ let1: chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ num1: chr  "1" "2" "3"
 $ let2: chr  "d" "e" "f"
 $ num2: chr  "4" "5" "6"
 $ num3: chr  "7" "8" "9"
 $ let3: chr  "g" "h" "i"
```

Then we want to change `num1`, `num2`, and `num3` into integer vectors (columns 2, 4, and 5).  For illustration, copy `df` to `df2` and then use `purrr::map`. Here I refer to the columns by their column number, but you could also use the names.

```
> df2 <- df
> df2[, c(2,4,5)] <- purrr::map(df2[, c(2,4,5)], as.integer)
> str(df2)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ let1: chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ num1: int  1 2 3
 $ let2: chr  "d" "e" "f"
 $ num2: int  4 5 6
 $ num3: int  7 8 9
 $ let3: chr  "g" "h" "i"
```

If you don't want to load any other packages, `lapply` will work:

```
> df3 <- df
> df3[, c(2,4,5)] <- lapply(df3[, c(2,4,5)], as.integer)
> str(df3)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ let1: chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ num1: int  1 2 3
 $ let2: chr  "d" "e" "f"
 $ num2: int  4 5 6
 $ num3: int  7 8 9
 $ let3: chr  "g" "h" "i"
```