# In R, why rm(list<-ls()) does not work when <- is also assignment?

Tags: r

According to the [R manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/assignOps.html),

> The operator <- can be used anywhere, whereas the operator = is only allowed at the top level (e.g., in the complete expression typed at the command prompt)

So I tried rm(list<-ls()) because <- operator can be used anywhere as said above, but R gave me an error saying "... must contain name or character strings".

rm(list=ls()) works without any problem. As far as I know, <- is a more universal assignment while = can be used under more strict circumstance. But why does using <- give an error when it comes to 'rm' function?

Comment: They don't do the same when setting function arguments. When used in a call, `<-` assigns a variable in the calling environment, but doesn't set the parameter name, while `=` does the opposite. What's happening here is like how `alist(x <- 1)` returns an unnamed list of an expression, while `alist(x = 1)` returns a named list of a number. This matters here because names are required for all keyword arguments (those after `...`).

Comment: @alistaire Thanks for your helpful comment. But what is the difference between a list of an expression and a list of a number? Since I cannot do the 'typeof' for the argument x in the function (i.e. alist(x=1) and alist(x<-1) ), I don't know exactly what the list of expressions and a list of numbers are!

Comment: If you call `str` on it or subset, you can see. An expression is an unevaluated language object. Assuming the argument you intend to pass to the parameter is a number, it will cause problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `rm()` uses non-standard evaluation by default. It tries to remove what you literally type for the parameters that are not `list=` (or `pos=` or `env=` or `inherits=`).

So you can do

```
a <- 10
rm(a)
```

Note that `a` is just interpreted as a symbol. It's not evaluated to return a value. When you call `rm(list<-ls())` you are expecting that expression to be evaluated, but it is not. It's trying to find a variable named `"list<-ls()"` but no such variable exists because no variable should have such a name. Additionally it has to be a "valid" variable name. From the `?make.names` help page

> A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed by a number

This means that it will not parse unusual variable names like those you can make by escaping symbols with back ticks or single quotes. Technically you can also do

```
a <- 10
rm("a")
```

because the non-standard evaluation checks if the parameter is a literal character value. But it will still not evaluate any expressions even if they will ultimately return a character value. For example

```
a <- 10
b <- "a"
rm(b)
```

What happens above is that `b` is removed, not `a`.

If you want to pass in a function that returns names of variables as stirngs (as `ls()` does), you need to use the named `list=` parameter. The `<-` operator does not work as a substitute for `=` for named parameters.

Comment: When you type ?rm on Rstudio, you can see that rm takes arguments including both **...(ellipsis)** and **list=chracter()**.  Does this mean that unless it is specified specifically as list=ls(), rm() takes only symbol such as your varaible 'a' which has 10 as a value?

Comment: Another question! I created two variable like this : 'list<-ls()'=c(1,2,3,4,5), y='2'. typeof(list<-ls) and typeof(y) both returns 'characters'. However rm(list<-ls()) does not work while rm('list<-ls()') works. Why do I need to add single quotation marks while rm(y) and rm('y') both works regardless of quotation marks?

Comment: @Jinoo I tried to add some more details to the answer. The thing to note is that `typeof` does not use non-standard evaluation, so it evaluates the parameters you pass to it. A more apt comparison is `typeof(quote(list<-ls))` and `typeof(quote(y))` the former being "language" (which is not something that can be a variable name) and the latter being "symbol" which is what a variable name is.

Answer (score 3):

You're reading the entry for assignment operations, whereas in the case of `rm(list = ls()`, the `=` is not used as an assignment operator, but to set an argument value in a function call (see the discussion in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1742550/8386140)).

Let's take an example to illustrate:

```r
formals(print)
#> $x
#> 
#> 
#> $...
# The first argument to print() is named x
print(x = "a")
#> [1] "a"
# We've only set the value of argument x, not assigned to x
x
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'x' not found
print(x <- "a")
#> [1] "a"
# Now we've assigned to x, and passed x as the first argument to print
x
#> [1] "a"
print(y <- "b")
#> [1] "b"
# It works with any variable name, since R can take variables by name or order
y
#> [1] "b"
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

#### Update

[alistaire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4497050/alistaire) posted an excellent comment to the question on this about the same time I answered that you should read also.

Answer (score 1):

`<-` is not more universal. It only works for assignment. `=` has two uses: assignment and argument passing. Inside a function, `=` performs argument assigning, which is what you want to do here. With `=`, you are not creating a variable `list` which has the value `ls()`; you are assigning to the parameter `list` of the function `rm()` the argument `ls()`.

The first argument to `rm()` is `...`, which must be strings or the names of variables to be removed. You passed `list <- ls()` which is neither a string nor a name, which is why you got the error. If you want to pass `ls()` to the `list` parameter in `rm()`, you need to use `=`, not `<-`.