# How to calculate the average of random data in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I have a large file with multiple columns and I've been asked to split the data into 2 parts. I have R split the data randomly by 70% into a group called `nTrain`, and 30% into a group called `nTest`.
I was able to split the data randomly, but I now need to calculate the AVERAGE of a specific column in the 70% random data and do the same for the 30% random data. Can someone please explain how to do so?

Thanks.

If it helps understand my situation, this is what I have so far in R:

```
length(DataFile)

(nData=nrow(DataFile))

DataFile

set.seed(0)

(trainIdx<- sample(seq(1,nrow(DataFile)), floor(nrow(DataFile)*0.70)))

> (nTrain=length(trainIdx))
[1] 15129

> (nTest=nData-nTrain)
[1] 6484
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Ronak.  I will read the info on how to ask a good question and how to give a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

1. In `R` convention you should stick to the `<-` operator for most types of assigments (you can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/what-are-the-differences-between-and-in-r)
   and
   [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/assignOps.html)).
2. The code/output you posted is incomplete, really (e.g., the output after the first line, `length(DataFile)`, is missing).

Let's go through this step by step.

#### 1. Create mock data

```
set.seed(1701)
DataFile <- sample(seq(0, 1, 0.01), 10000, replace = TRUE)
```

#### 2. Create a dataset

```
# This randomizes the order
DataSet <- sample(DataFile)
```

#### 3. Split Train and Test

```
split <- length(DataSet) * 0.7
# You use length() for one-dimensional objects, and
# nrow() for matrices, tables, etc.

DataTrain <- head(DataSet, split)
DataTest <- tail(DataSet, length(DataSet) - split)

# This approach avoids rounding errors when splitting and
# as our dataset is already randomized we can sample linearly.
```

#### 4. Calculate average

```
> mean(DataTrain)
[1] 0.5029891
> mean(DataTest)
[1] 0.496056
```

Comment: Thanks Roman for the step-by-step instructions.  I will try your process and let you know if I can get it to work.

Comment: the file that I'm pulling the data from has 20 columns with headers.  I need to pull the average of only 1 of the columns, for only 70% of the data.  Can you explain how I can do this?  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you post a `dput(head(data))` into your original post and specify the column? As a general approach, @AdamB showed the right method if you work with table-shaped data.