# Why there are different behaviour between assignment symbol “=” and “<-” in R?

Tags: r

I'm assigning values within the output list of a function, like:

```
nofun = function(sth){

something happening here

metrics = list(
metric1 = value1
metric2 <- value2 )

return(metrics)
}
```

Once I query `metrics`, I noticed that the use of  `<-` and `=` differs: the first ones only assigns the value to a variable with no name (i.e. `"x1"= value1`), while the second one applies also the correct name (i.e. `metric1 = value1`).

This behaviour is cited also for `data.frame` at the bottom of an [old more generic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/what-are-the-differences-between-and-in-r/1742550#1742550), but there is no explanation of this specific usage case.

It caused me quite many headaches and waste of time before noticing it, but I didn't find any other useful information.
thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between "=" and "<-" in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/what-are-the-differences-between-and-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define a named list you **have** to use the syntax `list(name1 = value1, name2 = value2, ...)`. Elements of the list defined in this way have an attribute `name` containing their name.

Writing `name2 <- value2` assigns `value2` to a variable `name2`. If you write this inside of a list definition (`list(name2 <- variable2)`) the variable is included in the list but no name attribute is defined. So it is equivalent to:

```
name2 <- variable2
list(name2)
```

You can compare both statements:

```
attributes(list(a=3))
# $names
# [1] "a"
attributes(list(a<-3))
# NULL
```

Comment: oh, great! so, the simple reason why this happens is because it is a *rule*.
So, as a rule of thumb, using "=" can be considered the best option for assigning values during the contruction of an object (data.frame/list/whatever)?

Comment: Exactly, inside of a function (except `<-` which is also a function itself) always use `=`.