# What does this assignment operator imply?

Tags: r, assignment-operator

I have been reading the "R Language Definition" PDF file downloaded from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.pdf). And on page 11 I read this:

[image: page 11 of the pdf file]

I wonder what is the difference between the `attr` and the `attr<-`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `attr` gets attributes eg `attr(iris,"class")`, `<-` assigns/allows you to modify

Comment: See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/what-are-the-differences-between-and-assignment-operators-in-r)

Comment: Than you all guys. From all the answers I conclude that, both `attr` and `attr<-` are functions. And they are similar to setters and getters in Java respectively. I hpoe I am right.

Answer (score 1):

"attr" get specific attributes of an object.

"attr<-" an object, the new value of the attribute, or NULL to remove the
attribute.

Comment: When you say `attr` can _set_ an attribute, it's actually `attr<-` that sets the attribute. That is, when you do `attr(x, "key") <- value`, this is actually calling `'attr<-'(x, "key", value)`