# Behaviour of scatterplot() function in car package in R with regards to argument names

Tags: r, plot, format, scatter-plot

I'm learning how to use the `car` package in R and I've run into a minor format/syntactical issue with regards to using the `scatterplot()` function. My personal preference when using functions in R is to use the name of the arguments when applying the function. So in this case I would write:

`scatterplot(formula = prestige ~ income, data = Prestige, id = list(n = 4))`

When I do this I am shot the error:

```
  > Error in scatterplot(formula = prestige ~ income, data = Prestige, id = list(n = 4)): 
   argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

But when writing the function without the `formula` argument in particular:

`scatterplot(prestige ~ income, data = Prestige, id = list(n = 4))`

Everything goes through just fine.

I'm trying to understand why this is the case? I have read up from a previous post on the difference between using `=` and `<-` as assignment operators in [What are the differences between "=" and "<-" assignment operators in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/what-are-the-differences-between-and-assignment-operators-in-r), but I don't think that is what is happening here. Is there a way to reconcile this? I do like to keep things along the lines of best practices so I don't fall into lazy habits.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me, try contacting `maintainer("car")` directly. Prof John Fox is very active on R-Help, he will probably sort it out quickly.

Comment: Will get in touch with him. Thanks.