# Assigning the variables inside the bracket

Tags: r

I have a small dataframe as below.

```
sad <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2), b = c(3, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
           "data.frame"))
```

Can anyone please help me as to what is the below operation doing?

```
 sad[, a := sad[, "Ma"] == "Y"]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3
2     2     4
```

When I execute the above operation, i get the same output, but not sure what is the intent here. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Nothing. its just an incorrect code in R.

Comment: Sorry. I edited my question. It is ````:=````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** After some research I found this: [What are the differences between "=" and "<-" assignment operators in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/what-are-the-differences-between-and-assignment-operators-in-r)

The answer by @Konrad Rudolf discusses the difference between `=` and `<-` and interestingly using `<-` instead of `=` will throw an error:

```
# in contrast to sad[, a = anything_here]

sad[, a <- anything_here]

error: Error in `[.tbl_df`(sad, , a <- anything) : object 'anything' not found`
```

also in **your example** if you use `<-`

```
sad[, a <- sad[, "Ma"] == "Y"]
```

And to conclude also from the mentioned site answer by @Nosredna discusses:

"Google's R style guide simplifies the issue by prohibiting the "=" for assignment. Not a bad choice."

**So all in all maybe it is an assignement issue.**

**First answer:**

Let's consider this: Breaking down what you have on the right side from the comma in closed brackets which operates on **columns**. On the other side the left side from comma would operate on rows:

And also consider as @Onyambu noted in the comments:
Note that `sad` is a tibble eg `sad[, a = anything_here]` will still produce a result. No error thrown

```
# will not work no column a (a is a object)

sad[, a]

# All rows and the column named "a" -> this will work
sad[, 'a']

# will not work because you want to get all rows and column "Ma" -> there is no colum Ma in sad
sad[, "Ma"]

# here you assign nothing to object a
a = sad[, "Ma"]

# consecutevily you compare a = sad[, "Ma"] (e.g. nothing) to string 'Y'
# will not work because 'Ma' column don't exist.
sad[, "Ma"] == "Y"
```

Comment: Anything will work. Note that `sad` is a tibble eg `sad[, a = anything_here]` will still produce a result. No error thrown

Comment: Yeah. thanks you for this. I tried to elaborate the understanding of OP code. I updated the answer!

Comment: Do you think its a bug? I mean it should throw an error or something. eg a crazy stuff like `sad[, a = ...f..g~?+-a:b~..]` works haha

Comment: You are completely right. I would also expect an error. But I am no that experienced, maybe I can research a little.