# `print` function, how to include/exclude colnames or position them?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, cat

### Motivation

The `head` function of `base` doesn't have a SKIP or RANGE feature, so I was writing a function to do that:

```
df.printHead = function(df, n=6, row.idx=1, ...)
    {
    idx = row.idx;          ## offset, e.g, SKIP
    nrow = nrow(df);
    # tails             
        lower = (idx - n);  if(lower < 1)    { lower = 1; }
        upper = lower + n;  if(upper > nrow) { upper = nrow; }
                            if(upper >= idx) { upper = idx - 1; }
    tails = df[ lower:upper, ];  rownames(tails) = lower:upper;
    print(tails, col.names=TRUE, col.at="top", ...);
    cat("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", "\n");
    # one
        one = df[idx, ]; rownames(one) = idx;
    print(one, col.names=FALSE, ...);
    cat("\n");
    cat("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", "\n"); 
    # heads     
        upper = (idx + n);  if(upper > nrow) { upper = nrow; }
        lower = upper - n;  if(lower < 1) { lower = 1; }
                            if(lower <= idx) { lower = idx + 1; }
    heads = df[ lower:upper , ];    rownames(heads) = lower:upper;
    print(heads, col.names=TRUE, col.at="bottom", ...);
    invisible(list("tails"=tails, "one"=one, "heads"=heads));
    }
```

### Examples (iris)

```
dim(iris);
df.printHead(iris, n=6, row.idx=4);
df.printHead(iris, n=6, row.idx=148);
```

### What output I get

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
142          6.9         3.1          5.1         2.3 virginica
143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
144          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3 virginica
145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
148          6.5           3          5.2           2 virginica

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
```

### What output I want

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
142          6.9         3.1          5.1         2.3 virginica
143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
144          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3 virginica
145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 

148          6.5           3          5.2           2 virginica

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 

149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
```

The alignment left-to-right is nice, since all of the data in print is coming from the same dataframe.  I am aware I can use `cat` and fully control the output.

**I am searching for a `print` solution as it best integrates with `base`**

https://rdrr.io/r/base/print.dataframe.html

```
This calls format which formats the data frame column-by-column, 
  then converts to a character matrix and dispatches 
    to the print method for matrices.
```

### Question

I have tried `col.names=TRUE` inside of `print`
I have also added `col.at="bottom"` and DEFAULT `col.at="top"` for the location if TRUE

`print` has the dots `...` so do I need to write my own Rcpp code or something to get this to work?

Can I `extend` the print.matrix formatting that works internally in R?  Can I write my own `formatter` that hooks into the `base`?  If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could utilize `capture.output()` and restructure it with `cat(..., sep = "\n")`:

```r
df.printHead = function(df, n=6, row.idx=1, ...)
{
  idx = row.idx;          ## offset, e.g, SKIP
  nrow = nrow(df);
  # tails             
  lower = (idx - n);  if(lower < 1)    { lower = 1; }
  upper = lower + n;  if(upper > nrow) { upper = nrow; }
  if(upper >= idx) { upper = idx - 1; }
  tails = df[ lower:upper, ];  rownames(tails) = lower:upper;
  print(tails);
  cat("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", "\n");
  # one
  one = df[idx, ]; rownames(one) = idx;
  printone <- capture.output(print(one));
  cat("\n");
  cat(printone[-1], sep = "\n");
  cat("\n");
  cat("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", "\n"); 
  # heads     
  upper = (idx + n);  if(upper > nrow) { upper = nrow; }
  lower = upper - n;  if(lower < 1) { lower = 1; }
  if(lower <= idx) { lower = idx + 1; }
  heads = df[ lower:upper , ];    rownames(heads) = lower:upper;
  printheads <- capture.output(print(heads));
  cat(printheads[-1], sep = "\n");
  cat(printheads[1], sep = "\n");
  invisible(list("tails"=tails, "one"=one, "heads"=heads));
}
```

Output:

```
df.printHead(iris, n=6, row.idx=148)

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
142          6.9         3.1          5.1         2.3 virginica
143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
144          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3 virginica
145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 

148          6.5           3          5.2           2 virginica

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
```

If you want you could of course make a function out of taking the arguments `col.names` and `col.at`. + There is no need for all your `;`'s + `<-` is usually preferred over `=`.

Comment: This is a very nice `base` solution.  I am now understanding where `tibble` came from, based on the ability to customize such things.  It is FUN to see it happen with `base`.  I have a `matrix.print` function that shows block partitioning, and with column truncation, I may end up using `cat` to write my own version of `tibble`.

Comment: `;` and `=` are standard syntax in interpreted C-languages.  One day R will grow up. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/ ... my coding practice is very intentional.  I can literally copy/paste in Rcpp, cleanup my datastructures and be done in C++.  When oh when will we have the incrementor `++i` or `i++`.  Once they kill the `<-` operator.  `--i` and `i--`.  What of `x<-3` vs `x < -3`?  Space also matters and the `;` is good practice as well.