# What is the proper function to list load tif files in R?

Tags: r, list, file, tiff

I have tried the following code:

```
tifs<-list.files(".", pattern=".TIF")
```

When I write `tifs` under this function I get a return in the Console that `character(0)`:  It is empty.  I have also tried using `tifs=` in lieu of `tifs<-`, to no avail.

I tried a few different ways of writing to list the files, one of which is explained above.  A screenshot is listed below.  I am very new to R, and cannot find anything out by googling it.

[image]

Comment: Please include your code as text, not an image.

Comment: If you check the documentation of `list.files` you’ll see how the `pattern` argument is supposed to be used. In a nutshell, it expects a regular expression and is case-sensitive so you need to write something like `pattern = "\\.tif$"`. This will list the files but it won’t load them!

Comment: And regarding `<-` vs `=`, please refer to [my answer explaining the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51564252/1968).

Comment: Also, in the screenshot it looks like you are using `","` (a comma) as the path.  I guess you meant to use a period.

Comment: Some other remarks: `dir()` and `list.files()` are two names for the same function; don’t use both, decide one and stick with it. And calling `setwd()` is almost never a good idea. You don’t need it, and interferes poorly with other code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph's comment about `pattern=` is spot-on, though I feel they understated "case" a little: if you have files in your current directory with a file extension of `.TIF`, both `pattern=".TIF"` and `pattern="\\.TIF$"` would have found them (the former just a little more "sloppily", perhaps), but neither will find `"file.tif"`.  You can use `list.files(..., ignore.case=TRUE)` to find files ending in `".TIF"`, `".tif"`, and everything in between.