# changing name in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I have this df

```
sports=data.frame(name=c('football','hockey','rugby'),
  minutes=c(90,70,80),
  type=c("outdoor","indoor","outdoor"))

sports2=c('volly',60,NA)

newsp=rbind(sports,sports2)
```

how do i change rugby to tennis?

I've tried

```
newsp["volly"]==["tennis"]    newsp["volly"]==newsp["tennis"]
```

and without the quotation marks

Comment: `newsp$name[newsp$name == "volly"] <- "tennis"` This means "set the name value to tennis in the subset of names where the name currently is volly."

Comment: @Mako212 nothing wrong with using `=` for assignment. If a new user is more comfortable with that, please don't go out of your way to push `<-` on them.

Comment: @GregorThomas I get that the two operators are functionally equivalent, but in terms of generally accepted style I've never seen `=` broadly used for assignment in package documentation or otherwise. Should we consider the difference between the two immaterial at this point? And is there an equivalent to `<<-` for assigning a global variable with `=`?

Comment: @Mako212 It's very much a style choice. There are a couple subtle differences [you can read about here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1742550/903061). `<<-` has no equivalent. I'm certainly in the minority in that I almost always use `=`, but I'm not alone.

Comment: If you want to change "rugby" to "tennis" why have you written "volly" below?

Comment: i meant volly to tennis

Answer (score -1):

You can use the revalue function from the plyr package.

```
revalue(newsp$name, c("rugby" = "tennis")) -> newsp$name
```